# MPV | configure shortcut to play next video file in a folder

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, video, configuration, mpv-media-player

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Hey there! A friend advertised mpv to me as the holy grail of media players, so I installed it, and I was wondering how to set a custom shortcut for going to the next file in a folder!
Example:

```bash
name@computer:~/Videos$ ls
1.mkv 2.mkv 3.mkv 4.mkv
name@computer:~$ mpv 1.mkv
```

mpv now opened. We are playing the file `1.mkv`. I wanna set a custom shortcut, on `F11`, to play the file `2.mkv`. If I then pressed `F11` again, `3.mkv` should play.

I already modified the default shortcuts by doing:

```bash
name@computer:~$ vim ~/.config/mpv/input.conf
```

and writing:

```
d add speed 0.1
s add speed -0.1
+ add speed 0.5
- add speed -0.5
ENTER add chapter 1
```

and stuff like that. It all worked flawlessly, and was very intuitive. But now I've hit a roadblock. I tried to add the functionality I described above, but couldn't. I looked everywhere, at the mpv website, at the github page, but nowhere could I find how to do this. There were options like "playlist-next" and "playlist-prev" but they didn't work at all, even tho the described functionality was "skip to the next/previous file".
[input.conf on github](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/blob/master/etc/input.conf)

So my question is: What do I have to do (or write into `input.conf`) in order to have a shortcut to go back and forth between video files in a folder?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://www.reddit.com/r/mpv/comments/nt959s/go_to_next_file_in_directory/

Answer (score 0):

I use [mpv-nextfile](https://github.com/jonniek/mpv-nextfile) on Windows 10 but I should work on Linux too.
Place `nextfile.lua` to your scripts folder.
Change the key bindings and paste it inside `input.conf` :

```
F10 script-binding previousfile

F11 script-binding nextfile
```